# ¿Cómo puedo filtrar un array de objetos en JavaScript por múltiples criterios?

Tags: javascript, array, objeto, filtro

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación web donde necesito filtrar un array de objetos en JavaScript basado en múltiples criterios. Cada objeto en el array tiene varias propiedades y quiero filtrarlos en función de diferentes condiciones. Por ejemplo, quiero filtrar los objetos que tienen un cierto valor en la propiedad "nombre" y otro valor en la propiedad "edad". He intentado usar el método filter() pero no estoy seguro de cómo aplicar múltiples condiciones de filtro.

¿Alguien puede proporcionar un ejemplo de cómo hacer esto de manera eficiente?

```js
const data = [
  { nombre: 'Juan', edad: 25, ciudad: 'Madrid' },
  { nombre: 'María', edad: 30, ciudad: 'Barcelona' },
  { nombre: 'Pedro', edad: 35, ciudad: 'Madrid' },
  { nombre: 'Ana', edad: 25, ciudad: 'Sevilla' }
];

const filtro = (array, criterios) => {
  return array.filter(item => {
    return Object.keys(criterios).every(key => {
      return item[key] === criterios[key];
    });
  });
};

const criteriosDeFiltro = { nombre: 'Juan', edad: 25 };
const resultados = filtro(data, criteriosDeFiltro);
console.log(resultados);
```

En este código, el array data contiene objetos con propiedades como "nombre", "edad" y "ciudad". Quiero filtrar estos objetos basándome en múltiples criterios, como el nombre y la edad en el ejemplo proporcionado.

¿Cómo puedo hacer esto de manera efectiva y elegante en JavaScript? ¡Cualquier ayuda sería apreciada!

Comment: Hola Matias, el código que publicas parece realizar exactamente lo que decis necesitar. ¿Cual sería el problema que tiene?

Comment: ¿Querés ingresar "dinámicamente" qué tipo de filtros querés aplicar?